# key/value pairs by name in Dictionary in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift

Is it possible to access the `key` and the `value` of single `Dictionary` entry by **key** & **value**, not **0** & **1**?

In the example:

```
let rockyPlanets: Dictionary<String, Int> = [
    // Alphabetical order
    "Earth": 3, "Mars": 4, "Mercury": 1, "Venus": 2
]
for eachPlanet in rockyPlanets {
    println("\(eachPlanet.0) is at position \(eachPlanet.1)")
}
```

How can I access the key/values by **key** or **value** (not index) in this fashion:

```
for eachPlanet in rockyPlanets {
    println("\(eachPlanet.key) is at position \(eachPlanet.value)")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for (key, value) in someDict {
    // ...
}
```

In your case:

```
for (planet, position) in rockyPlanets {
    println("\(planet) is at position \(position)")
}
```