# Named key/value pairs in a Swift dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Is there a way to have named key/value pairs in a Swift dictionaries? I'd rather use a name instead of an index number to refer to either the key or the value.

Unfortunately, [key/value pairs by name in Dictionary in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823651/key-value-pairs-by-name-in-dictionary-in-swift) only discusses referring to the keys and values in a for-loop. I'd like to give the keys and values a name when I declare them in the typealias so they can always be referred to by their names.

Please see the comment in the below code snippet to show what I mean:

```
typealias CalendarRules = [EKCalendar : [String]]
let calendarRules = buildCalendarRules() // builds the array.
let firstCalendarRule = calendarRules.first
print(firstCalendarRule.0)       // I'd like to write: print(firstCalendarRule.cal)
print(firstCalendarRule.1)       // I'd like to write: print(firstCalendarRule.theString)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with dictionaries, except very indirectly; and your CalendarRules type alias is irrelevant. Your `firstCalendarRule` is not a dictionary; it is a *tuple*. You are free to name the members of a tuple:

```
typealias Rule = (cal:String, string:String)
let d = ["I am a calendar":"I am a string"]
let firstRule : Rule = d.first!
print(firstRule.cal) // I am a calendar
```